# Display UML in a browser

Tags: xml, xslt, uml, xmi, argouml

I want to display UML diagram (Activity Diagram) on the browser

I don't want a specific way to create the UML , I can create it using any way to get what I want.

I searched about that and found nothing.

All UML Editors could export to XMI . I am expecting to find an already made XSL file to display this XMI file in the browser,but I can't find it.

Comment: Really couldn't find anything via search? Lots of results here: http://www.google.com/search?q=xmi+xslt

Comment: First result: http://www.objectsbydesign.com/projects/xmi_to_html.html

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible today because the model has a graphical and model separate layers. A solution would have been to use the adobe dynamic svg technology to drill down into the information which would be mapped to the project model.

It could work and would be a great technological innovation but I doubt anyone capital angel would invest money on the modeling market today !!

Comment: In fact, many tools store the graphical information (layout, size,..) also in the XMI file using proprietary formats. With the upcoming OMG standard this will be normalized and then such a tool would be feasible

Comment: Could be a normalized graphical layer but I really don't see how it would be possible. Having said that the question is about the model navigation inside a web interface this is why dynamic SVG is a serious candidate.

Answer (score 0):

The html export of the UML tool will show you the diagrams. E.g. Magicdraw and Enterprise Architect have this feature.